# Getting " has no method 'of' " error while using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm getting " has no method 'of' " error when I'm trying to use socket.io.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

At this line,I'm facing error,

```
var chat = socketio.of("/socket").on('connection',onSocketConnected);
```

My app.js :

```
var fs = require('fs')

    , http = require('http')

    , socketio = require('socket.io');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express ();

var chat = socketio.of("/socket").on('connection',onSocketConnected);

function onSocketConnected(socket){
   console.log("connected :"+socket.id);  
}

//in your existing callback function of progress
//send info to client 
var callback = function(state){
    console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
    console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
    console.log('percent', state.percent);
    io.sockets.emit('message', JSON.stringify({size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: fileName}));

} 

progress(request('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'), {
    throttle:0,   
    delay: 0       
})
.on('progress', callback) 

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name))
.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log("error");  
})
.on('close', function (err){
console.log("Download Complete"); 
})
```

Comment: Which version of `socket.io` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.3.7 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in your declaration `socketio = require('socket.io')`. The official documentation says:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// Listen
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. @jfriend00 also gives a useful answer with good explanation. Glad to help.

Comment: Ya its true,@jfriend00 had given a nice explanation.

Comment: Can you please help me,how to send this progress to the html page

Comment: It's already another question, where we need more info about implementation. I recommend open new question.

Comment: k fine.I'll open a new question den.

Comment: Hi Rishad,can u please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751439/how-to-link-app-js-and-html-page-so-that-i-should-display-the-progress-bar-in-th

Answer (score 2):

Your `socketio` variable is not initialized properly.  You need something like this:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Where `server` is an active HTTP server object.

Your code is this:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
```

Which just gets you the socket.io module, not an initialized and active instance.

---

Because of this, your `socketio` variable is the socket.io module, not an initialized and active instance.  It is the instance that has the `.of()` method.