# How to link app.js to html page,so that I should display the progress bar in the browser using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm unable to link the index.html page to app.js.I'm trying to send the progress to index.html.But,I'm failing here.How can I overcome this issue?Can anyone please help me out ...

My index.html :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />

<div id="progressbar">
</div>

<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:8085');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('message', function(data){
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
    maximum: 100,
    step: JSON.parse(data).percent
    });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
```

My app.js :

```
  var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');
var DOWNLOAD_DIR = '/usr/local/';
var file_name = 'googlenew.png' 

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express ();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("connected :"+socket.id);  

});


var callback = function(state){
    console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
    console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
    console.log('percent', state.percent);
    io.sockets.emit('message', JSON.stringify({size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: file_name}));

} 

progress(request('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'), {
    throttle:0,   
    delay: 0       
})
.on('progress', callback) 

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name))
.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log("error");  
})
.on('close', function (err){
console.log("Download Complete"); 
})
```

Updated app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');
var DOWNLOAD_DIR = '/usr/local/';
var file_name = 'googlenew.png' 

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("connected :"+socket.id);  

});


var callback = function(state){
    console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
    console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
    console.log('percent', state.percent);
    io.sockets.emit('message', JSON.stringify({size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: file_name}));

} 

progress(request('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'), {
    throttle:0,   
    delay: 0       
})
.on('progress', callback) 

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name))
.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log("error");  
})
.on('close', function (err){
console.log("Download Complete"); 
})


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Why did you incorporate my answer into your question already?  You should leave the question as it was so folks can see exactly what you originally asked and then see the checked answer.  This site is designed to work that way.  You don't put the answer into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing Express properly so `app` is not hooked to any web server and thus `app.get()` isn't active.

Change this:

```
var app = express ();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});
```

to this:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

See the basic "Hello World" app example in the [ExpressJS doc](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html).

And, you will also need to make routes for jquery.js, bootstrap.js, etc...  Remember, node.js doesn't serve any files by default.  Since they are static files, you will probably want to use `app.use(express.static(...))` to serve the static files.

Comment: I have updated my app.js code here.Still I'm unable to link to html page.Can you please check the code once and edit here

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya - what errors do you see in the console?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the console.But I'm unable see the progress bar in the browser

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya - your server-side call to `progress()` happens at server initialization so there is no client to share progress with yet.

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya - You'd have to describe what you're trying to accomplish with the `progress()` call.  I don't follow what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95310/discussion-between-gangigunta-divya-and-jfriend00).